# In a WordPress Gutenberg block how can I create a multiple checkboxes using a CheckboxControl in the InspectorControls

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to create a custom WordPress Gutenberg block with multiple checkboxes of taxonomy terms pulled via the Rest API. I'm able to do this with a SelectControl. With a SelectControl you can just set multiple to true. I don't believe the CheckboxControl has this option. I want to do this in the InspectorControls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of showing multiple CheckboxControls inside the InspectorControls. In this example I assume you have the API response with taxonomy terms saved in the `taxs` variable that is an object with key = tax ID and value = boolean (enabled / disabled).

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;

blocks.registerBlockType('my/block', {

  // Other properties likt title, icon...

  attributes: {
    // No source, so saved in comment
    taxs: {
      type: "object"
    }
  },

  edit: function(props) {

    var taxs = props.attributes.taxs;

    // Don't mutate the original object but make a copy of it and mutate that one
    function onTaxCheckChange(newValue) {
      var copy = Object.assign({}, taxs);
      copy[this] = newValue;
      props.setAttributes({taxs: copy});
    }

    var checkboxes = Object.keys(taxs).map(function(taxId) {
      return el(components.CheckboxControl, {
        onChange: onTaxCheckChange.bind(taxId),
        label: taxId,
        checked: taxs[taxId]
      });
    });

    return el(wp.element.Fragment, null,
      // InspectorControls elements
      el(wp.editor.InspectorControls, null,
        el('div', null, checkboxes)
      ),
      // Block editor elements, can be anything...
      el('p', null, 'My block'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice but does not change the UI checkbox state? I don't know about `withState` so I stored an indexed array of functions obtained from `element.useState()`. That is, `var [ isChecked, setChecked ] = element.useState(...); setCheckeds[taxId] = setChecked;`.  Then I called `setCheckeds[this]` in your function `onTaxCheckChange()`. Not the best perhaps. Thanks for the bind() suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to render elements in a loop, you have to set their states because it is object oriented. Their states values have to be merged with attributes values.

You should use js's map instead of jquery's each and work on a copy of your attributes value.

I don't know how to use apiFetch, so I give you a post_array exemple instead. Maybe you can use {withSelect}.

```
const posts_array = [{name: 'post_name', slug: 'post_slug'},{name: 'post_name', slug: 'post_slug'}]
const tracks = ('tracks' in attributes) ? attributes.tracks: new Object
const YourCheckBoxes = withState({
    checked_obj: Object.assign(new Object, tracks)
})( ( { checked_obj , setState } ) => (
    <ul>
    {   
        posts_array.map((v) => (
             <li><CheckboxControl
                className="check_items"
                label={v.name}
                checked={checked_obj[v.slug]}
                onChange={ ( check ) => {
                    check ? checked_obj[v.slug] = true : delete checked_obj[v.slug]
                    setAttributes({tracks : checked_obj}) 
                    setState({checked_obj})
                } }
            /></li>
        ) )
    }
    </ul>
) )
```

Then, you can call YourCheckBoxes in InspectorControls

```
<InspectorControls>
    <YourCheckBoxes />
</InspectorControls>
```

Answer (score -1):

To have multiple checkboxes you will need multiple CheckboxControls. Refer to the [documentation for CheckboxControl](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/components/src/checkbox-control) for its options.

Comment: Adding multiple checkboxes is easy but I'm trying to do it dynamically from the API and get setAttributes to work.